# HAProxy Only Sending Traffic To One Node

Tags: haproxy, mariadb

I have an HAProxy with IP 10.60.61.20 and three MariaDB nodes at IP .21, .22, .23, all of course in the same subnet. I have the MariaDB cluster sync'd and they can read/write to eachother, but when I setup the HAProxy, it is only sending the traffic to 10.60.61.21 (the first node). Even after I turn off mysql on the first node, the HAProxy says that there has been a connection error and it doesn't send traffic to the other two nodes. Has anyone seen this before? I just build 4 Ubuntu 12.04 servers, 3 are for the nodes and the other is the HAProxy. Here is my HAProxy .conf file:

```
global
    log 127.0.0.1 local0 notice
    user haproxy
    group haproxy

defaults
    log global
    retries 2
    timeout connect 3000
    timeout server 5000
    timeout client 5000

listen mysql-cluster
    bind 0.0.0.0:3306
    mode tcp
    option mysql-check user haproxy_check
    balance roundrobin
    server mariadb1 10.60.61.22:3306 check
    server mariadb2 10.60.61.21:3306 check
    server mariadb3 10.60.61.23:3306 check
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you everyone for all of your input. I have finally solved this issue, what happened was that during the install, I accessed the first MariaDB host and said, essentially, (I am not a mysql pro) "grant user haproxy_check access to any database with full permissions". But I didn't do that to the other servers as well. So HAProxy was able to login to the first server using the right username/password, but those user permissions didn't replicate to the other databases, so I had to manually go into each MariaDB server and create the entry for that user to login to any database. Once this happened, everything started working immediately. Again, thank you all for your insight. I assumed that because my galera cluster was in full replication that my entry on the first server would take on the rest, but that wasn't the case for a user access entry. However, all of the tables and fields and edits and such WERE replicating, which led me to believe that the permissions did too, but alas, they didn't.

Answer (score 0):

I would *guess* your problem is on the application side.

Since this is mode TCP, it is *going to balance TCP connections among the various servers* and not sql transactions. This means if your application doesn't use a *pool* of connections but just maintains a single open connection, that connection is going to remain open against the one server. If you application doesn't retry on failed connections, HAProxy won't magically move the failed TCP connection to another server.

I think a simple test would be to run something like the following command against the haproxy IP over and over again (however, don't run it within a single console session):

```
mysql -u monitor -p -e "show variables like 'server_id'"
```

Answer (score 0):

I would check the log on the `haproxy` load balancer.

```
# less /var/log/haproxy.log
```

You should see **UP** and **DOWN** messages. If you notice that it isn't failing quick enough, you could always change:

```
server mariadb1 10.60.61.22:3306 check
server mariadb2 10.60.61.21:3306 check
server mariadb3 10.60.61.23:3306 check
```

To something more aggressive such as `fail over after 2 failed checks, check ever second`:

```
server mariadb1 10.60.61.22:3306 check fall 2 inter 1000
server mariadb2 10.60.61.21:3306 check fall 2 inter 1000
server mariadb3 10.60.61.23:3306 check fall 2 inter 1000
```

DigitalOcean has [a great tutorial](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-use-haproxy-to-set-up-mysql-load-balancing--3) on this.